# Prefix to Post fix using C

Tags: c, string, data-structures, stack, expression

The question is:
WAP to convert a given Prefix expression into its equivalent Postfix

expression and evaluate it using stack.

I have written this code, it takes the input but doesn't display the output.

```
//header files

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>



//global variables
char stack[50];

int top = -1;

void push(char s)
{
stack[++top]=s;
}

//function to pop an element

char pop()
{
return stack[top--];
}

// funtion to check if the character is operator or not
int is_operator(char x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
        case '+':
        case '-':
        case '/':
        case '*':
    return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//function to Convert prefix to Postfix
void convert()
{
    int i,l;
    char op1,op2,tmp;

    char exp[50];
    printf("Enter the prefix expression: ");
    gets(exp);

    //length of expression
    l = strlen(exp);
    //scanning from right to left
    for(i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        //checking if the symbol is an operator
        if (is_operator(exp[i]))
        {
            //popping two operands from stack
            op1 = stack[top];
            pop();
            op2 = stack[top];
            pop();
            //concating the operands and operator
            tmp = op1 + op2 + exp[i];
            //Pushing the temporary string to stack
            push(tmp);
        }
        //if it is an operand
        else
        {
            //push the operand to the stack
            push((exp[i]));
        }
    }
    //printf("The postfix expression is: %s",stack[top].c_str());
        printf("%s ",stack[top]);
}

//main function
int main()
{
    
    convert();
    return 0;
}
```

when i run the code it takes the prefix expression but immediately after that it crashes and returns to the terminal?

Can anyone please help me with the code i am having difficulty in understanding what mistake i have made.
Also if possible give a little explanation what mistake i did in the code.

Comment: Best advice is to learn to debug effectively for yourself. Run your program in a debugger and step thru the code as it runs to trace its flow and variable values. From example, the debugger will instantly tell you the exact line of code that triggers the crash.

Comment: One other thing you should consider is to not assume the input is well-behaved. I bet that if you enter the input `*` then you'll crash because the first thing it does is access `stack[-1]`. And on that note, if you enter `1+2` then you'll pop and wind up in the same situation (after pushing `2` and then processing the `+`)

Comment: `printf("%s ",stack[top]);` That looks wrong because `top` will be the end of the string not the start. Try `printf("%s ",stack);`

Comment: `tmp = op1 + op2 + exp[i];` is not concatenation regardless of the comment written above this statement.

Answer (score 1):

1. In this algorithm, a stack of strings is required. But you are using an array of char.
2. The  `exp[i]` returns a `char`. So just can not expect `tmp = op1 + op2 + exp[i]` to concat them into a string in c.
3. In c `strcpy()` can be used to copy a string and `strcat()` can be used to concat strings.
4. There are several ways to convert a char to a string of one char tailing NULL. In this code `(char[2]){(char)exp[i], '\0'}` is used to get a string containing `exp[i]` and NULL char.
5. In the solution code there is a memory limitation. The input expression should be in 50 chars (including '\0') .

Solution code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char stack[50][50];
int top = -1;

void clear_stack() {
    top = -1 ;
}

void push(char *s)
{
    strcpy(stack[++top], s) ;
}

char* pop()
{
    return stack[top--];
}


int is_operator(char x)
{
    if(x == '+' ||x == '-'||x == '*'||x == '/'){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}


//function to Convert prefix to Postfix
void convert(char *exp)
{
    clear_stack() ;

    int i,l;
    char op1[50],op2[50];

    l = strlen(exp);

    //scanning from right to left
    for(i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        //checking if the symbol is an operator
        if (is_operator(exp[i]))
        {
            //popping two operands from stack
            strcpy(op1, pop()) ;
            strcpy(op2, pop()) ;;
            //concating the operands and operator
            strcat(op1 , strcat(op2 , (char[2]) {(char)exp[i], '\0'})) ;
            //Pushing the temporary string to stack
            push(op1);
        }
        //if it is an operand
        else
        {
            //push the operand to the stack
            push((char[2]){(char)exp[i], '\0'});
        }
    }
    //printf("The postfix expression is: %s",stack[top].c_str());
    printf("%s\n",stack[top]);
}

//main function
int main()
{
    convert("*-A/BC-/AKL");
    convert("+ab");
    convert("*+abc");
    convert("*a+bc");
    convert("+/ab/cd");
    convert("*+ab+cd");
    convert("-*+abcd");
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
ABC/-AK/L-*
ab+
ab+c*
abc+*
ab/cd/+
ab+cd+*
ab+c*d-
```